# Django development on Windows IDE but deployment on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to start development on Django for the first time and I'm looking to deploy the site on a Ubuntu server when production ready. I have never coded with anything other than Windows but I understand that Python references file structure differently on Windows compared to Linux. I would prefer to develop code that can be deployed easily after development. Hence I'm looking for a Windows IDE that syncs files with the deployment machine when saved so that I can run the tests over on the remote machine immediately. I would like to utilise venvs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use os.path.join().

## Example:

instead of

```
'output'+'/'+'log.txt'
```

do

```
os.path.join("output","log.txt").
```

This way your file structure issue would be solved.

**ps: Never concatenate strings manually to get file path.**